# React: Difference between argument with braces vs without braces

Tags: reactjs, typescript, reactjs-flux

Consider this function for example:

```
  onChange = (event, { newValue }) => {
    this.setState({
      value: newValue,
    });
  };
```

What is the difference between `{ newValue }` and just using `newValue`.
Example taken from [here](https://github.com/algolia/react-instantsearch/blob/master/examples/autocomplete/src/App-Multi-Index.js#L36).

Is i'm using typescript, is using

```
  onChange = (event, { newValue }: string) => {
    this.setState({
      value: newValue,
    });
  };
```

any different from

```
  onChange = (event, newValue: string) => {
    this.setState({
      value: newValue,
    });
  };
```

Thank you for helping me understand!

Comment: This is called object destructuring: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring There are lots of SO answers explaining it.

Comment: Thanks, just didn't know how to google what this is. I think i'll be able to take it from here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If as a second argument would be passed an object with keys eg.:

```
{value:'aaa', newValue: 'bbb', anotherValue: 'ccc'}
```

the second argument will take object property `newValue` as a value

In other words you can pass whole object as second argument but ONLY its `newValue` property will be used as a value of second argument